# How to setup .Net Core database connection to use MS SQL Server running in Docker container?

Tags: .net, sql-server, macos, docker, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an existing .Net Core 2.0 application using LocalDB for database. I work on macOS and cannot use LocalDB as far as I understand. I have seen recommendation to use MS SQL Server running in Docker container, but I haven't managed to configure connection string properly.

Existing connection string:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=My.Application;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
```

I am trying to connect to MSSQL on Docker with:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=My.Application;User id=foo; password=bar;",
```

or

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=My.Application;User=foo;Password=bar;",
```

resulting in error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: LocalDB is not supported on this Platform.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.LocalDB.GetLocalDBConnectionString(String localDbInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.GetLocalDBDataSource(String fullServerName, Boolean& error)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.CreateConnectionHandle(Object callbackObject, String fullServerName, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Byte[]& instanceName, Byte[]& spnBuffer, Boolean flushCache, Boolean async, Boolean parallel, Boolean isIntegratedSecurity)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.TdsParserStateObjectManaged.CreatePhysicalSNIHandle(String serverName, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Byte[]& instanceName, Byte[]& spnBuffer, Boolean flushCache, Boolean async, Boolean parallel, Boolean isIntegratedSecurity)
   ...
```

How do I make it work? Do I need to use different packages?

Comment: @LexLi ah thanks, it went fine after changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1,1433`